# Excel Power Query from ODBC

Tags: excel, odbc, powerquery, m

I have 2 queries, customers and contacts and I want to show the orders of each customer in a sheet in excel as follows:

**CUSTOMERS**

```
ID  NAME
1   CLIENT A
2   CLIENT B
3   CLIENT C
```

**CONTACTS**

```
ID  CUSTOMER_ID NAME    PHONE
1   1           NAME 1  999
2   1           NAME 2  000
3   2           NAME 3  888
4   2           NAME 4  333
5   2           NAME 5  111
6   3           NAME 6  777
7   3           NAME 7  555
8   1           NAME 8  444
```

**RESULT**

```
CLIENT A
NAME 1  999
NAME 2  000
NAME 8  444

CLIENT B
NAME 3  888
NAME 4  333
NAME 5  111

CLIENT C
NAME 6  777
NAME 7  555
```

I don't know much about Excel and I need some guidance on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task using **Power Query** please follow the steps,

[image]

---

• Select some cell in your Data Table,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the PQ Editor opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the 2 Tables Names,

• Paste the **M Code** below in place of what you see.

• And refer the notes

---

```
let

    //Source Table CONTACTStbl
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CONTACTStbl"]}[Content],
    DataTypeOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"CUSTOMER_ID", Int64.Type}, {"NAME", type text}, {"PHONE", Int64.Type}}),

    //Source Table CUSTOMERStbl
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CUSTOMERStbl"]}[Content],
    DataTypeTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTwo,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"NAME", type text}}),

    //Merge both the tables
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(DataTypeOne, {"CUSTOMER_ID"}, DataTypeTwo, {"ID"}, "CUSTOMERStbl", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded CUSTOMERStbl" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "CUSTOMERStbl", {"ID", "NAME"}, {"ID.1", "NAME.1"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded CUSTOMERStbl",{"NAME", "PHONE", "NAME.1"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

• Change the Table name as RESULTtbl before importing it back into Excel, note that you need to select **Only create connection.**

[image]

---

• Next open the same query connection **RESULTtbl** and right click to create a **reference** (Perform this thrice since 3 CLIENTS), change the query name with the respective **CLIENT NAME**.

[image]

[image]

• Filter Client Name and Remove the CLIENT Col

---

For **CLIENT A**

```
let
    Source = RESULTtbl,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([NAME.1] = "CLIENT A")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"NAME.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

The above M-Code is for **CLIENT A**, like wise you need to do for the others. Just copy from the Advance Editor and change the CLIENT NAME there. And import as table in **New Worksheet**

[image]

---

For **CLIENT B**

```
let
    Source = RESULTtbl,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([NAME.1] = "CLIENT B")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"NAME.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

For **CLIENT C**

```
let
    Source = RESULTtbl,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([NAME.1] = "CLIENT C")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"NAME.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

### EDIT

With the existing Power Query Connection(**RESULTtbl**), we can create a Pivot Table, and place the **CLIENT** field in **FILTERS** area of Pivot Table, while the **NAME** & **PHONE** to be placed in **ROWS** area.

---

• Click on **Data Tab** --> **Queries & Connections** --> Right Click on **RESULTtbl** --> **Load To** --> **Pivot Table Report** --> Select **New Worksheet** or **Existing Sheet** with cell reference --> press Ok.

[image]

---

• Next, from **Design Tab** under **Layout Group** turn off the **SUBTOTALS** (click on **Do not Show Subtotals**) as well as the **GRANDTOTALS** (click on **Off For Rows & Columns**), hide the buttons from **Pivot Table Analyze Tab**, make sure to select the **Report Layout** from **Design Tab** to select the **Show in Tabular Form**

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Finally run the **Show Report Filter Pages** -- From **Pivot Table Analyze Tab** under **Options** Menu, you will get the desired output, a gif. shown below for your perusal.

[image]

---

Download the workbook from here: **[CLIENT_WISE_REPORT](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ciAT3TovVxc9NLwzO?e=bMpb9f)**

Comment: It is correct, but the list of clients is much broader and create a query for each client I do not see, it can be hundreds. I don't know much about Excel, but I do this in PHP with foreach, I don't know if there is any way to do it in a similar way

Comment: @user2426415 please refer the edit, i have added a workbook as well as updated a gif to check

Comment: thank you very much, it works. Now I have a doubt, if I add a third table, for example the address table and I add it as the last row, it repeats the lines even if I do not repeat element labels selected.

Answer (score 2):

Open The PQ Editor, and Create Your Tables: You can Manually Enter them following : Home --> New Query Group --> Enter Data

[image: T1]

[image: T2]

Now You need to merge your queries using Merge Queries Function:

Home --> Combine Group --> Merge Queries (See picture)

[image: TTL]

Now you need to merge queries based on ID <> CUSTOMER_ID Columns:

See Picture:

[image: DREYR]

Then Expand The columns, and you will see a table like this:

[image: Expanded]

Then Filter The Name Column to the customer you want to see the result:

[image: Glglgl]

Finally Pick the one who load it into your worksheet, and finish task: In Excel You will see a different screen like this:

[image]

Click OK and go! Finished!